are stackpointer values in ARM assembly converted to int* in C if passed in the r0 register?
I want to write a small interrupt handler in ARM Assembly. It saves the registers r0-r12
onto the stack and then the lrregister. Then I pass the address of r0 on the stack to a C handler function.
I did this:
mov r0, #12 @for testing purposes
    mov r1, #13 @ for testing purposes
    mov r3, sp

    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12}
    push {lr}
    
    mov r0, sp
    add r0, #56
    bl prefetch_abort_C
    pop {lr}

void prefetch_abort_C(int* registers) {
    printf("prefetch abort. \n registers r0, r1: %i, %i \n", *registers, *(registers+1));
}

The problem is: I get 0 and 0 as output and I do not understand why.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/b/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Alphabetical-list-of-instructions/STMDB---STMFD "The lowest-numbered register is stored to the lowest memory address, through to the highest-numbered register to the highest memory address."  So r0 was pushed at address sp+4, not sp+56.

The answer to your question yesterday ((ARM assembly) how to address elements on the stack relative to the sp) quotes the same sentence of documentation that Nate did.  Seems like a duplicate.

This doesn't have anything to do with "converting" or the register where something is passed. A pointer is an absolute address, and adding an offset to sp does give you the absolute address of that stack slot. The issue here is simply that you got the offset wrong.

And I realized I also got it wrong on my comment on your other question, which maybe led to this confusion. Sorry about that.

Thanks for all your help. @PeterCordes I did not read all of what you linked so I missed the answer - not like I was too lazy to read it.
